# Amazon Cognito connection cannot find IdentityPool

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, token, amazon-cognito

I've spent a day trying to get Cognito working on my server. I find none of the documentation of much help as there are no clear examples of setting it all up.

I have the following code on my server:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
        "A**************",
        "+y*****************************");

AmazonCognitoIdentityClient client =
        new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(credentials);
GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest tokenRequest =
        new GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest();
tokenRequest.setIdentityPoolId("eu-west-1:be9d19a5-*******************");
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

//Key -> Developer Provider Name used when creating the identity pool
//Value -> Unique identifier of the user in your <u>backend</u>
map.put("access.com.cbn.postref", "fred");

//Duration of the generated OpenID Connect Token
tokenRequest.setLogins(map);
tokenRequest.setTokenDuration(1000l);

GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityResult result = client
        .getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(tokenRequest);
String identityId = result.getIdentityId();
String token = result.getToken();

System.out.println("id = " + identityId + "  token = " + token);
```

I have created an IAM user and used the public and private keys in the code above. I've created an IndentityPool on Cognito with the Dev. Auth. Id as given in the code: access.com.cbn.postref.

When I run this code I get an exception thus:

> com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.ResourceNotFoundException:
>   IdentityPool 'eu-west-1:be9d19a5-***********************' not found.
>   (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400

Generated at

```
GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityResult result = client
                .getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(tokenRequest);
```

I'm at a complete loss as to know how to proceed as I cannot see what I've done wrong. I did try getting the list of IdentityPools but that returns a list of 0 size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When accessing an identity pool in the eu-west-1 region, you must explicitly set the region of your client to use that region:

```
client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));
```

We are currently working on an example developer authenticated identities backend plus iOS/Android application we hope to release soon.

Comment: Thanks Bob - that worked and I would not have known this had you not pointed it out. One further question. It looks like I only need to create one user with appropriate privs to access S3. I imagine I use this one user and each user of my app will get a different token for connecting. Is that correct procedure, or do I have to create a new IAM user for every app user that registers on my server?

Comment: @cbn You should use a unique identifier for each user accessing your app so they get a unique cognito identity id. Otherwise your users will be able to access each other's data. To be clear this is an identifier in YOUR system. You do not need to create any additional assets in IAM or Cognito to make this work.